# Execute maven plugin regarless of directory or its contents

Tags: maven

I have developed a Maven plugin. 
I want to execute my plugin skipping any `pom.xml` (or other files that may affect the execution) that are in the directory.

The situation I have is: I am calling `mvn my.plugin:mygoal --settings=mysettings.xml`.
In `mysettings.xml` I define a repository from where I want to download `my.plugin`.
In the directory that I run the command, there already is a `pom.xml` file. When I execute my command, maven reads the `pom.xml` in my directory and tries to download some dependencies from repositories that I defined in `mysettings.xml`. It fails because the dependencies are not in the repositories defined in `mysettings.xml`.

Therefore:
I want to execute `mvn my.plugin:mygoal --settings=mysettings.xml` completely independently of the directory or its contents.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Maven will always look for a POM in the current directory.

Comment: If the directory already contained any `pom.xml` I could create a new "empty" `pom2.xml` and then just use `mvn -f "pom2.xml"` but it is a dirty fix.